# Apache 2.4 nasted location with exeptions

Tags: web-server, configuration, apache-2.4, web.config

I have a problem with my apache2.4 configuration. I have multiple services served by the apache reachable through:

www.example.com/http-service/ -> proxy pass config
www.example.com/webservice2/ -> proxy pass config
www.example.com/service3/ -> directory webpage
www.example.com/websock/ -> proxy pass config

Now I want to serve another page on:
www.example.com/

but when I want to create the location with a proxy pass config the current services are not served anymore an all the requests are redirected to the  -> www.example.com

Is there a solution that all the services are available?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName  
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/

SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/www-example-com.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/www-example-com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/www-example-com.chain
<Directory "/converee/">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Location /http-service>
   Require all granted
   AllowOverride None
   ProxyPass https://localhost:5200/http-service/
   ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:5200/http-service/
</Location>
ProxyPass /webservice2 https://127.0.0.1:6000/
ProxyPass /websock wss://127.0.0.1:6000/websock retry=3
ProxyPassReverse /webservice2 https://127.0.0.1:6000/
ProxyPassReverse /websock wss://127.0.0.1:6000/websock retry=3 
RedirectMatch permanent /webservice2$ /webservice2/

<Location />
   Allow from all
   AllowOverride None
   ProxyPass http://localhost:3030/
   ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3030/
</Location>

<Directory "/var/www/service3">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
     MultiViews  
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
</Directory>
```

Regards Tingle

Comment: Okay I found a hint to my solution -> to work with MatchLocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some readings I found a solution.

```
<LocationMatch "^(?!\/(service1|service2)\/?).*">
  #Service config for / except for /service1 or service2 
</LocationMatch>
```